# MongoDB v.6.2.0 connection w/ ES6 conventions not fetching properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6, fetch

I am doing the MERN Tutorial from MongoDB website and i am trying to convert the project in ES6 convention for JS.

The package.json look like this:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^6.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

The server.js look like this:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

import EXPRESS from "express";
const APP = EXPRESS();
import CORS from "cors";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

APP.use(EXPRESS.json());
APP.use(CORS());

import RECORD_ROUTES from "./routes/record.routes.js";

RECORD_ROUTES.recordRoutesEndpoint(APP)

// get driver connection
import DBO from "./db/conn.js";

APP.listen(PORT, async () => {
    // perform a database connection when the server starts
    try {
        await DBO.connectToServer();
        console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

the conn.js look like this:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

const DB_URI = process.env.ATLAS_URI;

const client = new MongoClient(DB_URI);

let _db;

const connectToServer = async () => {
    try {
        const DB = await client.connect();
        // Verify we got a good "db" object
        if (DB) {
            _db = DB.db("employees");
            console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");
        }
        return _db;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
};

const getDb = () => _db;

export default {
    connectToServer,
    getDb,
};
```

Note: The URL of process.env.ATLAS_URI work fine since i have tried another version and i have seen the query result on MongoDB database.

The project is currently starting and
`Successfully connected to MongoDB. Server is running on port: 5000`

Trying a POST request or a GET request seems to create an error saying:

```
/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:3657
                throw new BSONVersionError();
                      ^
BSONVersionError: Unsupported BSON version, bson types must be from bson 6.x.x

at serializeInto (/.../server/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:3657:23)
    at serializeObject (/.../server/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:3219:22)
    at serializeInto (/.../server/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:3452:25)
    at serializeObject (/.../server/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:3219:22)
    at serializeInto (/.../server/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:3653:25)
    at Object.serialize (/.../server/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:4035:32)
    at Msg.serializeBson (/.../server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/commands.js:386:21)
    at Msg.makeDocumentSegment (/.../server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/commands.js:380:37)
    at Msg.toBin (/.../server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/commands.js:369:29)
    at MessageStream.writeCommand (/.../server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:43:34)
```

Doing `npm ls bson` we obtain:

```
/server
├─┬ mongodb@6.2.0
│ └── bson@6.2.0
└─┬ mongoose@7.6.3
  ├── bson@5.5.1
  └─┬ mongodb@5.9.0
    └── bson@5.5.1 deduped
```

Some research told me : the project is using **`bson@6.2.0`**, which is compatible with MongoDB driver version **`6.2.0`**. However, it seems that **`mongoose`** is using an older version of **`bson`** (**`5.5.1`**). This can potentially cause compatibility issues.

Is there a way to not downgrading mongodb 6.2.0 or mongoose and keeping the ES6 conventions without getting errors?

You can find the tutorial at:
https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial

I have downgraded the version of mongodb to 4.17.0 and it will work fine but i would like to keep the 6.2.0 version.